# Configure flymake to use specific directory for temp files?

Tags: emacs, customization

I've been looking through the documentation and tried customizing and a variety of things, but no matter what I do it seems like Flymake just always places its temporary files into whatever directory the original file is in.

The main reason this is a big deal is because when I'm stepping through my programs using gdb, sometimes I step into an STL file, or other file in a non-user directory. Frequently this causes my gdb process to stop responding for some reason, which means that I have to go all the way back to the beginning and either globally disable Flymake or hope that I don't have to do another find-file in a dir that my emacs process doesn't have write access to.

Is there a good way to get flymake to always generate its temporary files in e.g. `~/.emacs.d/tmp`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent versions of Emacs only save "inplace".  Here's a quick hack to save "intemp":  http://blog.arithm.com/2011/01/27/save-_flymake-files-in-a-temporary-directory/

Comment: I had to modify the defun a little for python/flymake., but that actually worked. I added my modified defun to that page as a comment. And it needs `temporary-file-directory' to be defined, as in Jonatan Linden's answer.

Comment: @quodlibetor Did you find a general way that does not require to specify for several modes seperately, but generally (LaTeX, Python, etc)?

Comment: sorry @Dualinity I haven't needed this enough to try and make it that general.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me:

```
(setq temporary-file-directory "~/.emacs.d/tmp/")
```

Comment: I noticed, but never fixed, the fact that when I upgraded emacs this stopped working. nurikabe's answer in combination with yours did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but for C#, flymake redefines the flymake-get-make-cmdline function.

It returns a string, the command line to run for flymake.  I suppose you could modify that function to return whatever you want, including a command line that specifies temp file locations in some intelligent way, for whatever compiler you're running.